# NetBeans: Run Target to execute an external bat file

Tags: netbeans, batch-file, build, target

I have a JavaHelp project and I have a bat file that basically runs a jhindexer (to create help index).

I would like to make it so that every time I make a build (Run>Target>Other target>Final build - it would run the jhindexer bat on pre-compile. Unfortunately I can't seem to get it working.

Here is my build.xml bit:

```
<target name="-pre-compile"> 
    <echo message="Creating index"/>
    <property name="createIndex" value="${basedir}\" />
    <echo>${createIndex}</echo>
   <!--<exec command="cmd /C createIndex.bat" />--> //Says its deprecated  
    <exec dir="${createIndex}" executable="createIndex.bat">
        <arg file="cmd createIndex.bat" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

This code gives me:

```
Creating index
Y:\NetBeansProjects\JavaHelp\
Y:\NetBeansProjects\JavaHelp\build.xml:79: Execute failed: 
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "\createIndex.bat" (in directory "Y:\NetBeansProjects\JavaHelp"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I change it to:

```
   <exec command="cmd /C createIndex.bat" />

Creating index
Y:\NetBeansProjects\JavaHelp\
The command attribute is deprecated.
Please use the executable attribute and nested arg elements.
```

I can't seem to figure out a way to run the bat file...

Edit 1:

here is the contents of the bat file:

```
cd src\helpsetproject
..\..\javahelp\bin\jhindexer topics
```

It basically goes from basedir too the folder where Images, Topics folders are. Then I run jhindexer (which is in basedir\javahelp\bin) and give it topics (name of folder in the director i am in) as a parameter I guess. It works standalone, but not from Run Target in NetBeans.

Comment: Can you run the bat file by itself?  If that gives an error post the bat file.

Comment: @RGuggisberg I have added the contents of the bat file. It does run by itself (creates a JavaHelpSearch folder with all the indexes)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<target name="-pre-compile"> 
    <echo message="Creating index"/>
    <property name="createIndex" value="${basedir}\" />
    <echo>${createIndex}</echo>
    <exec dir="${createIndex}" executable="cmd">
        <arg line="/c createIndex.bat" />
    </exec>
</target>
```